# Display two variations of Wordpress blog

Tags: html, wordpress, integration

I am making a site for my band and have a good chunk coded (HTML, CSS, Javascript) and would like to incorporate a blog. BUT, I would like to have just a preview of maybe two or three blog posts on the homepage with a "read more" button that would take you to a separate "blog" or "news" page that displayed the full list of articles. Is there a way to do this?

I am open to possibly creating a WP theme, if this sort of this is possible with that, or any other CMS/blog type of integration. Here is a link to get a general idea: http://chrisbattenandthewoods.com/test/  You'll see the few "test" blog posts up top, and would ultimately like that to be the latest two, and then be able to go to a page that displays all of them, as I said before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the most part, if you're using Wordpress, you'll be using their PHP functions:

For the front page blurbs, you'd use:

```
<?php the_excerpt(__('(…)')); ?>
```

where what's between the parenthesis is what you'd like your text to be.

You'd need to add a separate hyperlink to the actual page, which is done like so:

```
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Link here</a>
```

Personally, I'd do something along these lines:

```
<?php $the_query = new WP_Query( 'showposts=10' ); ?>

<?php while ($the_query -> have_posts()) : $the_query -> the_post(); ?>
    <div class="archive">
        <?php the_post_thumbnail('full') ?>
        <font class="title"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" style="text-decoration: none;color: #777;"><?php the_title(); ?></a></font>
        <?php the_excerpt(__('(more…)')); ?>
    </div>
<?php endwhile;?>
```

The first line calls in the query of new posts, and I've set the number of posts to show.

The `while` statement makes sure there are actually posts to show, so that it doesn't break the layout.

The divs I used are to hold the post, you'll obviously be replacing that with your own. I merely added the title and excerpt into these posts, but there's plenty more to add. I see you've got a timestamp on that blog, so in WP you'd use `<?php the_time(); ?>`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for responding. I realize that I'm going to have to dive deeper into this and get a handle on PHP and the overall way Wordpress functions when creating a new theme. Two things that I'm concerned about: 1. I made the site using the Boostrap framework (I know that there is a Wordpress plugin for this, not sure if it's the way to go) 2. On the homepage of the site, the nav bar is in a different location than the sub pages, would that effect the way I make the header.php file? Or do I keep it the same but just put it lower on the page for the homepage. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Sorry, I can't help you with the Bootstrap issue, but you should give the Wordpress plugin a go and see if you've got any problems. As for the header, you make a separate page template. the header.php should contain what your header looks like for most of the pages, and if you've got any exceptions (in your case, the homepage), then make a template for that page (e.g. home.php), and leave the header.php out and code the header in directly.

Comment: Hey– Thanks again for your help. I ended up finding this link which helped me solve the problem: [display-wordpress-content-outside-of-your-blog](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/display-wordpress-content-outside-of-your-blog-corvid-works) Looking back at your code it makes more sense to me now, and I'm sure it's spot on, I was just able to follow the article a little better since I dont know PHP too well. One other question for you though. Since <?php the_exerpt(_( is not wrapped in a tag, how do you go about styling that?

Comment: @user3210921 `<?php the excerpt(); ?>` outputs a `<p>` element, so you could target it, in my example, the CSS selector `div.archive p {}` Alternatively, you could wrap that function in its own `div` or `span` tags and give that a class (not id, since this will be used multiple times), e.g. `<div class="excerpt"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></div>` Also, if my answer helped, please mark it as the answer.